# qualtrics sum must total 100

Tags: javascript, api, qualtrics

This is the code i tried and it is working fine for side by side question. My requirement is of 5 columns in one place and one column must total 100, qualtrics dosn't give the validation of must total 100 in side by side question.

steps:
1)hide the next button 
2)added next button2 and and click event to it.

Is there other way to do this?

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{

document.getElementById("NextButton").style.display = "none";

ButtonHTML = document.getElementById("Buttons").innerHTML;
ButtonHTML = ButtonHTML + "<input aria-label='Next' id='NextButton2'   class='NextButton Button' title='Next' name='NextButton2' value='  >>  ' data-runtime-disabled='runtime.Disabled' data-runtime-aria-label='runtime.ariaLabel' role='button' page-id='P_1425294269078' type='submit'>";

document.getElementById("Buttons").innerHTML = ButtonHTML;

document.getElementById("NextButton2").addEventListener("click", function(){
if(ColumnTotal()) {
  document.getElementById("NextButton").click();
}
});


  function ColumnTotal() {


    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('QR~QID190#2~1~1~TEXT').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('QR~QID190#2~2~1~TEXT').value;
    var txtThirdNumberValue = document.getElementById('QR~QID190#2~3~1~TEXT').value;
    var txtFourNumberValue = document.getElementById('QR~QID190#2~4~1~TEXT').value;
    var txtFiveNumberValue = document.getElementById('QR~QID190#2~5~1~TEXT').value;

    if(isNaN(txtFirstNumberValue)) {
      txtFirstNumberValue = 0;
    }

    if(isNaN(txtSecondNumberValue)) {
      txtSecondNumberValue = 0;
    }

    if(isNaN(txtThirdNumberValue)) {
      txtThirdNumberValue = 0;
    }

    if(isNaN(txtFourNumberValue)) {
      txtFourNumberValue = 0;
    }

    if(isNaN(txtFiveNumberValue)) {
      txtFiveNumberValue = 0;
    }

    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue)+ parseInt(txtThirdNumberValue)+ parseInt(txtFourNumberValue)+ parseInt(txtFiveNumberValue);

    if(result != 100) {
        alert("Please total the choices to 100.");
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}


});
```

So if there is anyone who knows Qualtrics and knows why it does this or any other methods this would be a help.

Comment: Please create jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer:
As I said in my original answer, you can use a Matrix Text Input question.  So, I tried it out and came up with this script:

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function() {
    var qid = this.questionId;
    $(qid).select('td.c4').last().down().hide();
    $(qid).select('td.c5').last().down().hide();
    var totalInput = $(qid).select('td.c6').last().down();
    totalInput.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
    totalInput.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    var c6 = $(qid).select('td.c6');
    for(var i=0; i < (c6.length - 1); i++) {
        c6[i].down().observe("keyup", function(event) {
            sumCol();
        }); 
    }   
    sumCol();   

    function sumCol() {
        var total = 0;
        for(var i=0; i < (c6.length - 1); i++) {
            var inputValue = parseInt(c6[i].down().value);
            if(isNaN(inputValue)) inputValue = 0;
            c6[i].down().value = inputValue;
            total = total + inputValue;
        }
        totalInput.value = total;
        if(total == 100) totalInput.style.color = "";
        else totalInput.style.color = "red";
    }   
});
```

So in the Matrix question the last row is a Total. In this example, the third input column (c6) is the one that is totaled and must add to 100.  The totals for the first two input columns (c4 and c5) are hidden.  The total is a readonly field so the respondent can't change it. The only other thing to do is add a Qualtrics Custom Validation rule so the total must equal 100.

To me this seems a better solution for a few reasons: the respondent gets immediate feedback on the total; it works like a Qualtrics Constant Sum question;  it is self contained in the question (it can coexist with other questions on a page); there is no need to mess with the Next Button.

[See example in Qualtrics Survey](https://marketinview.qualtrics.com/WRQualtricsSurveyEngine/?SID=SV_d3RKcDrONV9OOqh&SVID=&Preview=Block&ID=BL_806VMEtM3iop8wJ&Q_DONT_SAVE=1)